# Android ColorFilter empty constructor

Tags: android, bitmap, draw, colorfilter

I have a question. I'm trying to make a simple file manager, and when the user clicks on an item, that item is supposed to be tinted to look more orangeish (or any other color I specify). I was looking at the Paint's .setColorFilter(ColorFilter filter) method, and I wanted to use it to set the color I want the image to be tinted in and then later call drawBitmap(imagepath, x, y, p <--my Paint class with a color filter) method to display the Bitmap with a different color. The problem is that I have looked at the ColorFilter class (the one I'm supposed to pass to setColorFilter()) and it has an empty constructor, and only one method, which doesn't at all do what the class's name suggests it does.

Can someone give me some directions?
Thanks in advance.

Links:

[Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setColorFilter%28android.graphics.ColorFilter%29),
[ColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html)

Comment: see what classes extend `ColorFilter`

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I'll work on it and post a solution here later as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
Paint p = new Paint();

p.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#B3B3B3"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN));
```

Just put the hex color value for the color you want and then select a PorterDuff mode.

Have fun!